# Prove $(s_n)$ converges, where $s_{n+1} \lt r(s_n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $(s_n)$ is a sequence such that $s_{n+1} < r s_n$ where $r$ is a constant with $0<r<1$. Prove that $s_n$ converges. All values are positive.

I thought about maybe solving this through the Cauchy criterion and setting $s_{n+1} - r s_n < 0$ but not sure how to put an absolute value on it and setting it to be less than epsilon.

Comment: Are there no more assumption for this problem?

Comment: Isn't $(s_n) = \{0,-1,-2,-3, \dotsc\}$ a counterexample?

Comment: Do you know the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Notice $s_{n+1} < rs_n < r^2s_{n-1} < r^3s_{n-2}\cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets consider the series $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n$, since we have that
$$\dfrac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} < r < 1$$
we know $S$ converges (ratio test), hence what can we conclude about $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$?

Answer (score 0):

By induction, $0<s_n<r^ns_0\to 0$

Comment: Hagen, just letting you know this came up on Low Quality Post review because of "length and content." I'm skipping.

Answer (score 0):

By assumption
$$
s_{n+1} < r s_{n}
$$
for all $n$ with $s_n >0, r \in (0,1)$.
Thus, using this iteratively, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we get
$$
s_{n+1} < r s_{n} < r^2 s_{n-1} < r^3 s_{n-2} < ... <r^{n+1} s_0.
$$
Since $r^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we see that also $s_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, which proves the claim.